# JAX-WS Password Type PasswordText

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, wsse

I've got a simple command line Java JAX-WS app to test a SOAP request, but the server is expecting the Password Type to be PasswordText and I'm stumped on how to set this...

The code looks like so:

```
@WebServiceRef
private static final HelloService helloService = new HelloService(url, new QName(
        URL, "HelloService"));

public static void main(final String... args) {

    try {
        final HelloPort helloPort = helloService.getHelloPort();
        final BindingProvider hB = ((BindingProvider) helloPort);
        hB.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                                   END_POINT_ADDRESS);
        hB.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
                                   USERNAME);
        hB.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
                                   PASSWORD);
        ...
```

I've tested the request using SOAP-UI so I know it's working. Any help on setting the password type would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That will set the username and password for Basic HTTP authentication.  If you've tested it in SoapUI, I'm guessing the 'PasswordText' value you speak of is the 'WSS-Password Type' in the request details pane.  That sets WSS security, not HTTP security.

With JAX-WS in Java6 you need to attach a SOAPHandler to inject the WSS-Usertoken into the SOAP Header.  There are plenty of bits and bobs about this round the net, but I couldn't find one single link to post, so here's some code instead to get you going...

To add a handler you need something like:

```
final Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) servicePort).getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
if (handlerList == null)
    handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();

handlerList.add(new SecurityHandler());
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList); // <- important!
```

Then the SecurityHandler class will do the deed.  Handlers are general things and get called for both successful messages and for faults, but perhaps more importantly they get called in *both* message directions - for the outgoing request and then again for the incoming response.  You only want to handle outgoing messages.  So you'll need something like:

```
public final class SecurityHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext msgCtx) {

        // Indicator telling us which direction this message is going in
        final Boolean outInd = (Boolean) msgCtx.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        // Handler must only add security headers to outbound messages
        if (outInd.booleanValue()) {
            try {
                // Get the SOAP Envelope
                final SOAPEnvelope envelope = msgCtx.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

                // Header may or may not exist yet
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
                if (header == null)
                    header = envelope.addHeader();

                // Add WSS Usertoken Element Tree 
                final SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse",
                        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                final SOAPElement userToken = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
                userToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse").addTextNode("MyWSSUsername");
                userToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse").addTextNode("MyWSSPassword");

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOG.error(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    ...
    // Other required methods on interface need no guts
}
```

I've made a few assumptions here, but hopefully it'll get you going!

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked perfectly and your answer was almost impossible to find by Googling, so allow me to add some keywords.  JAX-WS WSSE

Comment: When using this code I got the following exception in by log: `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl addChildElement
SEVERE: SAAJ0101: Parent of a SOAPBodyElement has to be a SOAPBody`.

Comment: This doesn't always work - you need to use a factory object to generate the elements to avoid the dreaded SAAJ0101 error. See @cleison answer instead.

Comment: @Ben Well, this is 8 years old now - I would hope that things have moved on a bit since my original answer!

Answer (score 8):

If you implement SOAPHandler interface, the method msgCtx.getMessage() will render the entire XML, and if you are working with big files you will have Out of Memory errors. I tested with UsernameToken authentication on JAX-WS client and it works:

```
String SECURITY_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
String PASSWORD_TYPE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText";
String AUTH_PREFIX = "wss";

MyService service = new MyService();
MyServicePort port = service.getMyServicePort();

try {
    SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPElement security = soapFactory.createElement("Security", AUTH_PREFIX, SECURITY_NS);
    SOAPElement uToken = soapFactory.createElement("UsernameToken", AUTH_PREFIX, SECURITY_NS);
    SOAPElement username = soapFactory.createElement("Username", AUTH_PREFIX, SECURITY_NS);
    username.addTextNode("username");

    SOAPElement pass = soapFactory.createElement("Password", AUTH_PREFIX, SECURITY_NS);
    pass.addAttribute(new QName("Type"), PASSWORD_TYPE);
    pass.addTextNode("password");

    uToken.addChildElement(username);
    uToken.addChildElement(pass);
    security.addChildElement(uToken);

    Header header = Headers.create(security);
    ((WSBindingProvider) port).setOutboundHeaders(header);

    // now, call webservice

} catch (SOAPException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit:** You should add the "rt.jar" from jre to classpath.

Comment: I tries this but im getting javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.message.DOMHeader cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.outgoing.SecurityHeader
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:250)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1063)

Comment: i think it is related to having the metro ws jar in the classpath- but i need that one