# JAXWS-Security: basic authentication password text

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I secured my SOAP WS following by this example:
[JAX-WS Basic authentication](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/jax-ws-basic-authentication?showall=&start=1)

but there is one problem: how can I define than I want to use wss-password type PasswordText?

Comment: there is some similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096183/jax-ws-password-type-passwordtext

Comment: I saw, but that thread about client. And I try to secure the service.