# How to create a SOAP API request with UsernameToken in JAVA?

Tags: java, soap, usernametoken

My program is running in a server and needs to make a client side call to a SOAP API using Java.

I used SOUPUI to generate a client stub code for the API service WSDL by JAX-WS Artifacts. The API server side requires a UsernameToken. I used the jaxws-ri document example "How do I do basic authentication in JAX-WS ?" as something like below to call the API.

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();
Hello proxy = (service.getHelloPort());

((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "userfoo");
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passbar"); 

Output output = proxy.doAction();
return output.getResult();
```

But I get below exception in the step of `proxy.doAction()`.

> Exception: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS6500E: There is no caller identity candidate that can be used to login. ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@30ed30ed Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
>
> at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:258)
>           Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Could you please give me some advice on how to call the API with the UsernameToken? Or is there any server side configuration needed?

Comment: 'Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.' Did you check?

Comment: Thanks. Checked the server log with additional stacktrace as updated above. But I still has no hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer from the post [JAX-WS Password Type PasswordText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096183/jax-ws-password-type-passwordtext). I solved my problem. Also, with reference from the post [JAX-WS : SOAP handler in client side](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/).