# Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: Unable to create MessageFactory: Provider for javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory cannot be found

Tags: java

I need to communicate with webservice via SoapHttpPort. 
Machine run Apache Tomcat 8.5.23 and Apache Karaf 4.

Webservice need settings of authorization in Soap  "Authorization - Basic" and "Outgoing-wss".

When I call port, I receive WebServiceException:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: **Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:1000**
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:159)

- First fix

I tried recommended fix (SecurityHandler class).

[JAX-WS Password Type PasswordText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096183/jax-ws-password-type-passwordtext)

But this fix didn´t solve problem.

I receive another exception.

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: **Problem writing SAAJ model to stream:Unable to create MessageFactory: Provider for javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory cannot be found**
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:159)

- Second fix

I tried recommended fixes.

https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-reportincident-wssecurity

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/38499-unable-to-create-message-factory-for-soap-provider-org-apache-axis-soap-messagefacto

But this fixes didn´t solve problem. WebServiceException is still the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.