# JAX-WS, Authentication and Authorization - How to?

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, jax-ws, access-control

What is the best way to do authentication and authorization in web services?

I am developing a set of web services, requiring role based access control.
Using metro - SOAP, simple java without EJBs.

- I want to Authenticate the user just one time, using username and
  password, to be matched against a data base. In the subsequent calls.
- I would like to use some kind of session management. Could be some
  session id, retrieved to the client at login, to be presented in all
  calls.

So Far:

- Read  [authentication using a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613212/jax-ws-and-basic-authentication-when-user-names-and-passwords-are-in-a-database)  - but I want application level validation;
- Read [application authentication with jax-ws](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/) - but i don't want to do the authentication mechanism every time;
- I think I can use a SOAP Handler, to intercept all the messages, and do the authorization control in the hander, using some session identifier token, that comes with the message, that can be matched against an identifier saved in the data base, in the login web method.

**EDIT:**

I still have some questions:

- How to know the name of the web method being called?
- What kind of token should I use?
- How to pass this token between calls?

**EDIT 2**

Because of @ag112 answer:

I'm using Glassfish.

I use WS-Policy and WS-Security to encrypt and sign the messages. Using Mutual Certificate Authentication. I would like to complement this message level security between applications, with the authentication and authorization for the users also in message level.

I am just developing the services, and I don't know almost nothing the clients, just that they could be created in different languages.

At this point I think the most important thing is to do what ever I need to do to authenticate and authentication the users, I the most easy way to be implemented for the client applications.

Comment: Did you know you may answer your own question? BTW, I think it's a good question and I'm surprised there weren't more responses.  I'm not familiar with JAAS, but I did find this article: http://drdobbs.com/web-development/208402532.   I looks like you went in the right direction.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help, finally someone! I created an answer as you said, wit the road so far. As soon as possible I will read the page you referred, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all the help, I create this answer to simplify, and summarize all the ideas that was discussed.

The questions has 2 requisites:

- Message level security;
- One time authentication.

With ag112 help, this is hard to do, or to elegant in any way. So here are to conclusions:

- For message level security send the user
  credentials every time (place it in SOAP header);
- For one time authentication use transport level security, and do a
  session management.

I prefer the first one, because the message level was the biggest requisite.

Answer (score 4):

@Luis: Here are my inputs.

Well exact solution for your problem depends upon kind of web service clients you expect, do you have control over web service client system, your app server etc.....but assuming you don't have any control over web service client, for you it is just a SOAP message over HTTP transport, here is probable solution.

You can of course performs session management & authentication at message level or transport level. It means either you can have session token and auth token information in SOAP message or you can use standard HTTP Session and HTTP authentication mechanism.

Of course transport level solution is much simpler and industry wide standard in case if transport layer is HTTP. For  message level, ws specifications like ws-security can be used. 
Your each web service request is simple HTTP GET/POST identified by a unique HTTP URI.
Typically in jax-ws metro environment, WSServlet is one which entry servlet for any web service call and which eventually delegates the call to right service provider implementation class. Since you application is going to be deployed in web server, you can exploit all session and authentication facilities provided by J2ee web container.

Since you are looking for role-based access control, I would use standard `<web-resource-collection>` in web.xml to specify which role you would like to have in case of particular HTTP URI. You can use standard JAAS login module which can do authentication and populates the JAAS subject with role. If user name/password are provided in SOAP XML, JAAS login module can also search/parse SOAP XML to retrieve those information. JAAS/app server will automatically create auth token and store it as cookie so that each subsequent request need not to go through authentication process again. This is all J2ee standard. You can find plenty of help on internet on this. Please let me know your app server so that I can provide you additional details.

If you still want to use SOAP message level session management, authentication & authorization process, then  to provide you more details, may I know more details about your client side.

**EDIT1:**
Well based on your further inputs, here is my more thoughts:
Message security namely encryption and signature needs to happen each message travels between server and client. where as message authentication- you intend to do once and give a session token/auth token to client for subsequent calls.

Question still remains: if you put a unique session Identifier in SOAP response of first time authentication, do you expect client to parse SOAP response XML and ensure that client should send you session identifier each time in subsequent SOAP requests. 
**OR**
You want to keep session management transparent to client and for client it needs to send username/password token first time and subsequent calls need not require any username/password token. In this case you would need to rely on transport based session management for e.g. HTTP cookies

Now what is the best for you depends upon your use case. Can you tell me what is expected use case flow? how another system (web service client) makes more than one service call to your system? Is another system user driven/some background process?  What is exact need that you want only first service call to go through authentication process not subsequent calls?

PS: Glassfish server provides a way of configuring message authentication provider which automatically enables/disables message level authentication.

**EDIT2:**
I understand you do not want to store user credentials in client app and web service server need those user credentials.
OAuth is open standard protocol which allows site A to access user's private data on site B. Ultimate idea is site A gets auth token which has specific expiry time. So Token containing encrypted from of user credentials or jsession id help you avoid need of re-authentication. **You only need to decide where you want to keep token at client app side**
You can keep token as cookie if transport is HTTP protocol.

Having said that ofcourse passing user credentials each time seems bit easier and straight forward.

Comment: Clients will use various services. My idea about a single time authentication, was to allow the client app to ask the user for the credentials, and don't need to store it. Something like OAuth (I thinks). But maybe could be easer to send the username/password in every call, and incorporate this in the message level security.

Comment: The main goal is the message level security, so I think for this I must abdicate the single time authentication, and have the client to send every time the user credentials in the SOAP header.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go for [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/securing-a-web-service.html).

It used JAAS with WS-Security.

I hope the link is useful.

Answer (score 0):

As had no answers, following @unhillbilly advise, I answer my own question, with the progress so far:

> How to know the name of the web method
>   being called;

Using a SOAP handler, finding the name of the first element in the body.

> What kind of token should I use;

I decide to use a 128 bits token, representing each session. The Webservices, continue to be session-less, the key is just for authorizations purposes.

> How to pass this token between calls.

For the login web method the result has the token, in each subsequent calls, the token is a parameter.

is there a better answer?

Comment: You can store the token in your message header no need to pollute the API with not relevant parameters.
That is how most of the frameworks handle this